# Adding 1D array to 2D array by initializing each row of the 2D array with 1D array

Tags: java, arrays

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while I'm using array1[x].length
I tried to debug the program &  stops while copying the last row of array1.

````
public static double[][] addRow(double[][] array1, double[] array2){
        double[][] copy=new double[array1.length+1][];
        for(int x=0;x<array1.length;x++){
          for(int y=0;y<array1[x].length;y++){
              double[] temp=new double [array1[x].length];
              temp[x]=array1[x][y];
              System.out.print(temp[x]+" ");
          }System.out.println();
            
           
        }
       
       
        return copy;
    }```
````

Comment: @RandyCasburn i'm already using '<' instead of '<='

Comment: I just ran your code after cleaning it up and do not get any errors.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I used length-1 and ran the code, no errors but it does not copy the last row of the original 2D array.